# httpClient.GetStreamAsync (add username and password)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

In my application I load a .pdf file from a password protected site.
This works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.
I suspect that this is due to whether my browser knows the username and password or not.

This is my code in the controller:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://example.com/example2/example3/" + pdf.name + "") ;
using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\pdf-" + pdf.name + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Dispose();
}
```

Is there a way that I can pass username and password with the link?

Thank for your help

Comment: Do you specifically mean that the target website uses [Basic Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), or something else?  How you authenticate against any given HTTP resource depends entirely on how it expects you to authenticate, which we don't know.

Comment: Not related but if you use the `fileStream` with `using` then you don't need to call explicitly the `Dispose`. Also you don't need the block operator `{}` in your example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a username and password when making an HTTP request using `HttpClient` by using the `HttpClientHandler` class to configure credentials.

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var responseStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://example.com/example2/example3/" + pdf.name + "");
using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\pdf-" + pdf.name + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Dispose();
}
```